# How to send values of hyperlinks to another form?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages

I have two forms in visual studio, which one is the "master page" and the other one is "login form" connected to master page. what I want to do is sending values of hyperlinks which are placed in master page, to the login page. for example: when its first time compiled, all hyperlink's enabled values will be false and if we enter the correct data in login page(user name and pass) then all hyperlink's value will be true and enabled. any help will be appreciated, my deepest regards...

```
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (user.Text == "kbu123" && pass.Text == "123")
            {

link1.enabled = true;
link2.enabled = true;
link3.enabled = true;
link4.enabled = true;         
link5.enabled = true;      


            }
```

here is the master page:

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{





     void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        link1.Enabled = false;
        link2.Enabled = false;
        link3.Enabled = false;
        link4.Enabled = false;
        link5.Enabled = false;


    }
}
```